# Binding TextBlock based on selection in ComboBox

Tags: wpf, binding, textblock, autosuggest, dynamically-generated

When I make selection in ComboBox, and then type some text in TextBox, I want to have visible AutoSuggestion list of ID or FirstName or LastName (based on ComboBox Selection) that contains typed string in TextBox. Like this, now it works only for FirstName.

I have problem to somehow set dynamically binding for TextBlock.
Please Help.
Thanks in advance! Marina

I have ComboBox:

```
 <ComboBox Height="23" Name="cbAttrib" Width="120" Margin="0,8,0,0">
          <ComboBoxItem>ID</ComboBoxItem>
          <ComboBoxItem>FirstName</ComboBoxItem>
          <ComboBoxItem>LastName</ComboBoxItem>             
  </ComboBox>
```

I have TextBox:

```
<TextBox Name="txtSearch" TextChanged="txtAutoSuggestName_TextChanged"/>
```

And this ListBox:

```
 <ListBox Name="listBoxSuggestion" Visibility="Hidden" SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock DataContext="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

and in code I have this methods:

```
private void txtAutoSuggestName_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        listBoxSuggestion.Items.Clear();
        if (txtSearch.Text != "")
        {
            ComboBoxItem cb = (ComboBoxItem)cbAttrib.SelectedItem;                
            Collection<Person> namelist = proxy.PersonSearch(txtSearch.Text, cb.Content.ToString());               
            if (namelist.Count > 0)
            {                   
                listBoxSuggestion.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                foreach (var obj in namelist)
                {
                    listBoxSuggestion.Items.Add(obj);                        
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            listBoxSuggestion.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        }
    }

    private void ListBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.AddedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            txtSearch.Text = (e.AddedItems[0] as Person).FirstName.ToString();
            listBoxSuggestion.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not binding the `Text` so nothing will display

You just bind the [`DataContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext.aspx), which does nothing if there are no additional bindings which will be relative to it. Just swap that (or add `Text="{Binding}"` which will bind to the `DataContext` which is the `FirstName`) and if your logic is correct it should work.

*(Instead of clearing and adding to `Items` you should just set the `ItemsSource` instead. `listBoxSuggestion.ItemsSource = namelist;`)*

**Edit:** To make the binding work for different suggestions change the binding path to `Value` and make the `ItemsSource` a collection of some simple objects with a `Value` property (e.g. use LINQ and anonymous objects).

Comment: Yes, I already typed Text instead DataContext, its works, but just for FirstName. I want it to bind with ID, and LastName too, based on ComboBox selection

Comment: @marinadra: Well, just change the binding path to `Value` and make the `ItemsSource` a collection of some simple objects with a `Value` property (e.g. use LINQ and anonymous objects), you probably will not need the full Person just for the suggestions list, right?